# How to count the occurance of a word in google search result using python and beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So, I am trying to count the number of occurrence of a phrase in the google search result. I have a query q and 3 options a1, a2 and a3. My code is

```
base = "http://www.google.com"
url = "http://www.google.com/search?q="+ q

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
for item in soup.select(".r a"):
  if a1 in item.text:
     c1=c1+1
  if a2 in item.text:
     c2=c2+1
  if a3 in item.text:
     c3=c3+1

print str(a1)+":"+str(c1)
print str(a2)+":"+str(c2)
print str(a3)+":"+str(c3)
```

This counts the number of occurence in the search result heading. How can I modify this code to get it to search in the small description that comes under each search result too.

Comment: You need to provide an example of the response.text - please read [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below to extract both the headline and the description of each of the results:

```
for result in soup.select('#ires .g'):
    footer = result.select_one('.s .st')

    if not footer:
        # means we're in a div for query images, skipping
        continue

    headline = result.select_one('.r a').text
    description = footer.text
    print(headline, description)
```